# Why is my referenced DLL not being included in my packages/builds?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I referenced a dll (System.Data.SQLite) and it works fine when I debug it. However it seems to be referencing the DLL from my Program Files rather than copying it to a package and including it in the build. It's not in my packages.config nor is it in prj/packages.

Answer (score 1):

With the project loaded, open the Solution Explorer and find the reference to the DLL you are having the problem with. In the properties menu for that reference there should be an option to "Copy local". Set that to true and when the package is built, it should pull the DLL in.

[image: Copy Local setting for reference]

Comment: I tried that already, it still wants to look up the DLL in Program files rather than my project folder. Thanks though!

Comment: Did you build in Release or Debug? Not sure how much a difference it will make but worth trying if you haven't.

Comment: I did in both. No avail :(